# TinyMCE with DigitalOcean Space in Django

Tags: django, image, upload, tinymce, media

I am currently working on building blog site using django and DigitalOcean Space. I've connected everything so static and media files automatically get saved to DigitalOcean space. However, I've been trying to get images in content (TinyMCE HTMLField()) get saved to DigitalOcean Space but seems to be not working. If I drag and drop the image to TinyMCE richtext area, it gets img src from my local path. If I do Upload, Source address seems to be generated with right path, but it's not saving the images to Space.

I currently have

In settings.py, TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG

```
'images_upload_url': '/upload_image/'
```

In views.py,

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        file_name_suffix = file_obj.name.split(".")[-1]
        if file_name_suffix not in ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", ]:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Wrong file format"})

        upload_time = timezone.now()
        path = os.path.join(
            settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'tinymce',
            str(upload_time.year),
            str(upload_time.month),
            str(upload_time.day)
        )
        
        # If there is no such path, create
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)

        file_path = os.path.join(path, file_obj.name)

        file_url = f'{settings.MEDIA_URL}tinymce/{upload_time.year}/{upload_time.month}/{upload_time.day}/{file_obj.name}'

        client.upload_file('file_obj', 'blmakerspace-spaces', 'file_url')

        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            return JsonResponse({
                "message": "file already exist",
                'location': file_url
            })

        with open(file_path, 'wb+') as f:
            for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
                f.write(chunk)

        return JsonResponse({
            'message': 'Image uploaded successfully',
            'location': file_url
        })
    return JsonResponse({'detail': "Wrong request"})
```

and urls.py set to

```
path('upload_image/', upload_image)
```

When I run this in local server, it gets saved to media folder and everything works. However, it won't work in production mode..

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still actual, first check field type for uploaded files should be FileField in models.py.

After: **if request.method == "POST":**

you need to get object to save, for example:

```
user_id = request.user.id
userdata = Data.objects.get(user=user_id)
```

Instead of:

```
with open(file_path, 'wb+') as f:
    for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
        f.write(chunk)
```

Use next code:

```
# full_filename - file name with format (ex. file.txt)

full_filename = 'your_file_name'    
userdata.your_field_name.save(full_filename, files.File(open(file_url, 'rb')))
userdata.save()
```

With this approach I successfully upload files to spaces of DO.